# How to get http response code from browser activity?

Tags: android, http, browser, networking

Is there a way to get HTTP response code from Browser activity launched from another Android application?

Since I haven't found any occurrences of "setResult" string in BrowserActivity source code, I assume startActivityForResult won't do much.

If not I'll probably stick with HEAD request from my activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to get HTTP response code from Browser activity launched from another Android application?

No, sorry. For starters, what page would you get the result for? The user could view 1000 pages before returning to you.